# Sharing to social media won't include image

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook, blogs, sharing

I am in the throws of setting up a blog for my business on a subdomain ([blog.twocan.co](http://blog.twocan.co))

For the blogging purposes I am going the easy route of a simple wordpress install.

Key to our marketing is to be able to share short posts accompanied by a large image on social media.

I want to be able to share any blog posts directly to facebook or linkedin but unfortunately when I click the share button the popup box only includes the text to share and not the image.

I have looked at the mark-up and can see that the image is inside the `<article></article>` tags.

Here is the image tag itself:

```
<img src="https://i1.wp.com/blog.twocan.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/yolo.png?fit=800%2C500" class="attachment-full size-full wp-post-image" alt="English test" srcset="https://i1.wp.com/blog.twocan.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/yolo.png?w=800 800w, https://i1.wp.com/blog.twocan.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/yolo.png?resize=300%2C188 300w, https://i1.wp.com/blog.twocan.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/yolo.png?resize=768%2C480 768w" sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px" width="800" height="500">
```

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/when-sharing-on-social-media-images-not-showing/  check this it may help you

Comment: Hmm, I checked my uploads directory permission and it is 755... not sure if that is the issue, but thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried sharing a post on facebook and it showing image.

Comment: Okay, very interesting, could be my addblocker, thanks for taking the time to test.

Comment: Tried it on two different browsers and a different computer and it still is not showing... this is what I am seeing: http://imgur.com/a/FeXyy

Comment: May I ask what browser you are using?

Comment: Okay, things seem to b working now... I added a new post and it is accepting it okay. Thanks for your help Gokul!

Comment: I am using chrome, for facebook you can use the OG markup as #benoti told, I can see the image after sharing only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share image with common social network, you need to add `open graph` meta to the header [about the protocol](http://ogp.me).

This can be done with a plugin or directly within the theme.

You will find a lot of tutorial on the web, but, you'll need to retrieve the featured image and write something like that:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

From fb developper example
[Fb OG markup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup)